# Hosting and accessing web pages on ubuntu virtual server

Tags: webserver

I am just a beginner. I have installed an Ubuntu virtual server 14.03 on a widows 8.1 host.I have lamp server ,phpmyadmin installed and working fine. I can access files on both the host and guest machine through putty and winsp. I just want to know for a start how host web pages from the host and access them from the browser. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to browser and type http://localhost/, it's a default virtual host and files located in **/var/www/html** directory. For creating simple virtual host like **example-com**, follow these steps:

1. Open **/etc/hosts** and add to the end `127.0.0.1 example-com`.
2. Create directory **/var/www/example-com**: `sudo mkdir /var/www/example-com`.
3. Copy **index.html** and other files from **/var/www/html** to **/var/www/example-com**.
4. Create **example-com.conf** in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** and add this code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example-com
    ServerAlias example-com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example-com

    <Directory /var/www/example-com>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

5. Enable virtual host: `sudo a2ensite example-com.conf`.
6. Reload Apache: `sudo service apache2 reload`.
7. Go to browser and type http://example-com/.

Comment: I thank you very much for your detailed and timely explanation